# Scrollbar click makes div disappear IE9+ / Windows 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, windows-8

Because there are a couple of skinned select boxes on my site, I am using dropkick.js, which essentially replaces the select boxes with interactive divs. If the list is larger than the max-height, the overflow-auto makes scrollbars appear. It works fine on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

On Windows 8 + IE9 & IE10 a scrollbar appears, but when I click or try to drag it, the div hides!

[> Link to the page](http://www.sameninvogtland.nl/en/)

I have only found a slightly similar issue on a Bootstrap UI combobox but that script did not work for me, because dropkick.js does not use Bootstrap and adapting the script did not solve the problem.

[> Link to similar bug](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/issues/64)

I was hoping it could be fixed with stopPropagation on the div but no luck on that either. Tried -ms-overflow-style:scrollbar but that does not change the behaviour.

Has anyone stumbled across a working fix for this in IE9+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem last week on one of my projects.

I solved it by changing the "click" event for closing the dropdown to "mousedown".

For some strange reason IE9+, on Windows 8, considers the scrollbar outside of the DOM element for click and mouseup events but for mousedown event it accepts the scrollbar as part of the DOM element.

By the way, I tried to reproduce the bug on your site but couldn't(Tested on IE10/Windows 8).